# Is Pelforth brune an ale or a lager?

Tags: beer-styles, clone-recipe

For being a commercial beer, I find it not too bad. For the few info I collected it seems that Pelforth uses ale yeast. Is it correct?

From wikipedia

> En 1935, Jean Deflandre, fils d'Armand, parvient à assembler deux malts d'orge et utilise la fermentation haute, avec une levure anglaise

In english:

> In 1935 Jean Deflandre [...] uses high fermentation, with English yeast.

But I have no info about any possible change after 1935.

Comment: It's an English style Brown Ale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelforth Brune is a great beer...I've been after a recipe for a long time. 
This is what I've found out about Pelforth.

Pelforth is a Bock, which is closer to lager than ale.
Pelforth,  was first brewed in 1935 using two different types of malt and English yeast 
Alcohol Content 6.5 % 
Bitterness 21. EBU
Colour 70.0 EBC 
It takes 43kg per hectoliter, that's a lot of malt
An hectoliter = 100ltr so that into gallons is 21.99 gallon, but 43kg div 4 = 10.75kg per 25ltr brew (5gal)

Which comes out @ 1.100 which sounds high!!But you need to scale it down from those figures as their mash eff's are different to ours.

23.5 ltr and 75% efficiency = 6.5kg of grains giving 6.2% abv

I do now have a recipe from a fellow brewer, it's AG if your interested?? I've not made it yet as I only got hold of the malt last week and have not had the time to try it. The guy is sending me a bottle soon to try, but he did say that it's very close to the beer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not at AG level yet :) If it is a Bock it should made with lager yeast then?

Comment: This is what we don't know, it states 2 kinds of malt and English yeast. Now the malt you would think they would use local or maybe German malt, same with the hops...but it does say English yeast, which I would go for Notts. You could do an extract brew.

Comment: Bock's are traditionally brewed with Lager yeast, as fruity esters/ aromas are a a fault of that style.
http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style05.php#1b